# jQuery sort checkboxes inside div's based on value

Tags: jquery, sorting, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes being generated by a plugin in Wordpress.
I don't have the option to sort these checkboxes so I would like to have them sorted based on their value, with the highest first.

the HTML generated looks like this:

```
<div class="wpgmza_filter_container" id="wpgmza_filter_container_5">
        <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder_first">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="0">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0">All</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="1">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1">Airco</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="2">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2">Vent</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried the following code:

```
function sortByID(a, b)
{
return (a.children(“input”).val() > b.children("input").val()) ? 1 : -1;
}

var container = jQuery("div.wpgmza_filter_container");
container.children("div").sort(sortByID).appendTo(container);
```

Comment: Firstly, please include the code you've tried yourself. Secondly, should the 'All' option remain the first one, regardless of its `value`?

Comment: ...aaaaand your question is? Please show us what code you tried which didn't work, including any errors. We won't write your code for you but we'll help you fix a problem you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your sort logic is that you're comparing strings, and you're also sorting the children of `.wpgmza_filter_container`, of which there is only one. You need to instead sort the children of `.wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder`. You are also using an invalid double quote character in your sort logic. Try this:

```js
function sortByValue(a, b) {
  var aVal = parseInt($(a).find('input').val(), 10),
    bVal = parseInt($(b).find('input').val(), 10);
  return aVal < bVal;
}

var $container = $("div.wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder");
$container.children("div").sort(sortByValue).appendTo($container);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpgmza_filter_container" id="wpgmza_filter_container_5">
  <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder_first">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="0">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0">All</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="1">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1">Airco</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="2">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2">Vent</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to ensure that the 'All' selection remains first in the list, you can exclude the filter logic from that div using `:not`:

```
$container.children('div:not(".wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder_first")').sort(sortByValue).appendTo($container);
```

Comment: very fast and descriptive. +1 .No wonder you have such a good reputation

Comment: BTW his html structure not changed at all, so swipe of values will be also ans option?Isn't it?(for this particular case only not in general)