# Sort checkboxes based on their values (in specific order)

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have checkboxes that are placed in a particular order by a wordpress plugin.

The generated HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="wpgmza_filter_container" id="wpgmza_filter_container_5">
        <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder_first">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="0">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0">All</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="2">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2">Airco</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_3" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="3">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_3">Vent</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="5">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">Sun</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
                <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="1">
                <div>
                    <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1">One</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The following code sorts based (from high to low) based on value:

```
function sortByID(a, b)
{
return (a.children(“input”).val() > b.children("input").val()) ? 1 : -1;
}

var container = jQuery("div.wpgmza_filter_container");
container.children("div").sort(sortByID).appendTo(container);
```

Is it possible to sort them based on a list of values I define?
I want them to be displayed in this order (value-based):
3,5,0,1,2

Comment: Why not just make an array and append them based on the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort items given in a non-sequential manner you can specify the ordering in an array and then compare the `indexOf()` of the given values in that array.

Taking my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120355/jquery-sort-checkboxes-inside-divs-based-on-value), you can expand the logic like this:

```js
function sortByValue(a, b) {
  var aVal = parseInt($(a).find('input').val(), 10),
    bVal = parseInt($(b).find('input').val(), 10);
  return order.indexOf(aVal) > order.indexOf(bVal);
}

var order = [3, 5, 0, 1, 2];
var $container = $("div.wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder");
$container.children("div").sort(sortByValue).appendTo($container);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpgmza_filter_container" id="wpgmza_filter_container_5">
  <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_holder wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder_first">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="0">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_0">All</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="2">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_2">Airco</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_3" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="3">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_3">Vent</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="5">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_5">Sun</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_item_holder">
      <input type="checkbox" class="wpgmza_checkbox form-control" id="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1" name="wpgmza_cat_checkbox" mid="5" value="1">
      <div>
        <label for="wpgmza_cat_checkbox_1">One</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```